# How to display an alert box?

Tags: javascript, php

The following code actually submits and with the same i need to display an alert box showing message has been sent.

Code :

```
<input type="button" class="Jdvs_Btn" onclick="send_reply('SEND_REPLY', <? echo $clsSurvey->feedback_id?>);" value="SEND" style="font-weight:bold;width:95px;height:30px;float:left; margin-right:5px;" />
```

And the Javascript

Code:

```
if(action == "SEND_REPLY")
{
if( frm.email.value == "" )
{
   alert("Please fill your email.");
   frm.email.focus();
   return false;
}   
else if( validateEmailAddress(frm.email.value) == false )
{
    alert("Please fill a valid email.");
    frm.email.focus();
    return;
}
else if ((tinymce.EditorManager.get('content_to_send').getContent()) == '')
{
    alert("Please enter content to send.");
    return;
}
else
{
    frm.form_action.value = action;
    frm.submit(); 
    alert('Message Sent Successfully');
}
```

}

The code for mailing is:
This is where the validation and other are done, i need to display an alert box here
Code:

```
function sendReply()
{
    echo $this->feedback_id;
    $this->checkAndUpdateReply($this->feedback_id,$this->content_to_send);
    $Message = nl2br($this->content_to_send);
    $mailMessage = "
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>constant('_SHORT_PRODUCT_NAME') - Feedback Mail</title>
    </head>
    <body>";
            $Message = nl2br($this->content_to_send);
        $mailMessage.= $Message."
    <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'width='100%'>
    <tr>
    <td style='$css_class' align='left'><br/>Email: "._EMAIL_INFO."</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style='$css_height' align='left'><br /><b>Note</b>:- This is an automatically generated email , Please dont reply back to this mail.</td>
    </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>";    
    $mailSubject= constant('_SHORT_PRODUCT_NAME').' - FeedBack Reply';
    $clsEmailTempalte = new clsEmailTemplate($connect, ""); 
    $clsEmailTempalte->sendMail($mailSubject,$mailMessage,$this->email);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, your code so far?

Answer (score 2):

At the end of your `send_reply` javascript function just do an `alert("Mail Sent");`

If you're using ajax (e.g. with jQuery) you'll need to add your alert to the callback.

For jQuery:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
```

Comment: If the javascript gets to that point, the message has been sent, assuming you're running your ajax call above.

Comment: if( frm.email.value == "" )
{
 alert("Please fill your email.");
 return false;
}else
   {
   
    frm.form_action.value = action;
    frm.submit(); 
    alert('Message Sent Successfully');
   }

Comment: This is why Goikiu asked you to share all your code. Looks like you're doing a simple post so the page will change after your submit. On the new page use your alert.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript function `send_reply` just add the line

```
alert("Message sent");
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `alert("message has been sent");` at the end of your js function.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this (using jQuery). I would call the php file that sends the email using ajax like so:

Your HTML:

```
<input type='button' id='submit_form' data-id='<? echo $clsSurvey->feedback_id?>' />
```

Your Javascript:

```
$('#submit_form').click(function(e){

    // To stop the form submitting on button click if you want it to...
    e.preventDefault();

    // Send the id via post to the mailscript
    $.ajax({
        url: 'mailscript.php',
        type: 'POST'
        data: {
            id: $(this).attr('data-id')
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        // Use data if you want to return something from the script and add to the message maybe?
        alert('Add your message in here');
    });

});
```

Then just add your mailing php inside the mailscript.php (or whatever you want to call it). whenever your script has completed it's job, the done function will fire showing your alert.